# is there a calculation for no load current on BLDC motor?

Tags: current, motor, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, torque

I am calculating various values for a range of motors. However, I need to find the no load current of a motor or io to allow me to calculate other values, based on the information I have below for a sample motor can this be done?

- Kv (RPM/v):   2100    kv
- Power (Watts):    2100    W
- Max Current (Amps):   140 A
- Max Voltage (Volts):  15  V
- Resistance (Ohms):    0.007   Ω
- Poles:    4
- Weight (Grams):   329 g

Comment: YOu would need no-load speed at 15V too

Comment: okay if we take 2100x15 we get a no load speed of 31,500 RPM please can you tell me how i can work this out.

Comment: YOu would only get that if there were no friction and windage in the motor. it will settle at some lower speed with no added load. Of course, in reality whatever load you are driving with this will likely be a lot more than that.

Comment: If you COULD get it up to 35,500 rpm the no load current would actually be zero.

Comment: I know the figures that you base these calculations on are also going to be different to real world values I'm simply asking how I calculate.

Comment: If you know the ACTUAL no-load speed, you can calculate the back EMF from the Kv value. Subtract that from the terminal voltage and divide by the resistance.

Comment: Though the above is just a first approximation.

Comment: I calculated the back emf at 0.004547 if I follow the calculation in your previous comment it gives me - 2142.85 this doesn't sound correct

Comment: Your back emf should be close to 15V....

Comment: I used the back emf constant which is the same as the torque constant this was calculated and checked on another post.

Comment: WHat speed did you use?

Comment: To calculate torque constant you don't use speed Kt = 60/(2 x π x kv).

Comment: YOu are confusing yourself... Again, if you want to know the no  load current you need to know either the no-load speed or the friction and windage torque at that speed. For an ideal motor the no-load current = zero.

Comment: Of course, it also depends on how you are driving it and the efficiency there of...

Comment: re: "To calculate torque constant you don't use speed " Not to calculate Kt, but actual torque yes you do... as the speed goes up the available current goes down...

Comment: @JonRB this is your field is it not? Any input

Answer (score 1):

No load current is zero amperes.

KV 2100 = 2100 RPM/V = 35 R/Vs = 220 rad/Vs

So, Ke,Kt = 1/220 = 0.00455 [Vs/rad] = 0.00455 [Nm/A]

$$U=K_e\cdot\omega + R\cdot I $$

EDIT:

\$T=K_e\cdot I \$   or  \$I=\dfrac{T}{K_e}\$ so if T=0 then current is zero. Else you would have to know the no load torque, which could be the ball bearing friction and air drag at known speed.

The derived Ke from KV that was actually measured in laboratory consists of a test setup. This is a second motor coupled to the shaft and spin as much as the current is zero - no load current. In such situation the applied voltage equals the back emf voltage \$ U=K_e\cdot\omega\$, knowing \$U\$ and \$\omega\$ is it possible to estimate \$K_e\$ or KV in your case. So the motor is spinning at 35,500 RPM at 15V, but not by himself, rather by the help of the coupled motor from the setup.